# What kind of decryption algorithm could this be?

Tags: cryptography, encryption

for a assignment in our university we have to find the decryption algorithm for a ciphertext. 
I already found the correct decryption for every letter but i still dont know wich cipher is used. (Our only hint was its kinda like the caesar cipher)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JXRFk.png]

(This is how letters are decrypted. First row is converted to third row, i have also written the number of the letter in the alphabet to maybe find some numeric decrypt algorithm)

Here is the ciphertext. For those who are interested in it:

> xituih, rinsyf ltgiqtl mwc liqu sy mrim bgixt, ktxieut rt ril
>   iymsxsbimtl mrim, sy mrt yimehig xcehut ca tntymu, uexr wcegl kt mrt
>   xcylexm ca nthxsyftmchsv, gtintu mrt ihdq eylth bhtmtyut ca hisusyf
>   htxhesmu iyl xinighq: rt bgixtu khemeu, i qceyf diy, sy xcddiyl ca
>   mrtut achxtu; rt fsntu rsd syumhexmscyu mrim mrt xinighq urcegl hiyft
>   iu tvmtyusntgq iu bcuuskgt sy igg lshtxmscyu; mrim rt wcegl tvthm
>   rsdutga ycm mc kt ikutym ahcd mrt xidb gcyfth mriy mrhtt liqu. rinsyf
>   ihhiyftl mrtut dimmthu, rt dihxrtu mc nstyyi kq iu gcyf zcehytqu iu rt
>   xiy, wrty rsu cwy ucglsthu lsl ycm tvbtxm rsd. asylsyf mrtht i ahtur
>   kclq ca xinighq, wrsxr rt ril utym cy mc mrim bgixt utnthig liqu
>   ktacht, dihxrsyf syxtuuiymgq ysfrm iyl liq, rt ilniyxtl hibslgq
>   mrhcefr mrt mthhsmchq ca mrt itles symc mrim ca mrt gsyfcytu, sy wrsxr
>   mwc gtfscyu wtht wsymthsyf, mrim, sa iyq bgiy iaatxmsyf rsu cwy uiatmq
>   urcegl rint ktty chfiysotl kq mrt itles, rt dsfrm ltatim sm kq mrt
>   hibslsmq ca rsu dcntdtymu. wrty rt ihhsntl mrtht, rt utylu syachdimscy
>   mc mrt htum ca mrt gtfscyu, iyl fimrthu igg rsu ihdq symc cyt bgixt
>   ktacht symtggsftyxt ca rsu ihhsnig xcegl kt iyyceyxtl mc mrt ihnthys.
>   nthxsyftmchsv, cy rtihsyf mrsu xshxedumiyxt, gtilu kixj rsu ihdq symc
>   mrt xceymhq ca mrt ksmehsftu; iyl iamth dihxrsyf ahcd sm mc fthfcnsi,
>   i mcwy ca mrt kcss, wrcd xituih ril utmmgtl mrtht iamth ltatimsyf mrtd
>   sy mrt rtgntmsiy wih, iyl ril htylthtl mhskemihq mc mrt itles, rt
>   ltmthdsytl mc immixj sm.

The only possible algorithm i found until now is the simple substition with a new alphabet which in my case is fpomuglr....q But im not sure if its really just that.

I know this is actually a board for asking programming questions, but since this is kinda programming related and i know there are a some programming people who are really into cryptography i decided to ask you guys if you maybe find some algorithm in it. Furthermore when we found the actual decryption algorithm we also have to code it.

Greets Jack

Comment: Yup. Simple substitution cipher. Since you already have the key, you just have to implement the cipher and you should be done.

Comment: What a boring piece of text, closing as too localized (you know what to do already anyway).

Comment: In case you don't, iterate through all the characters of the text, calculate the location in the alphabet (relative to the character 'a', or using `indexOf` in the alphabet), then substitute it by the replacement character at the same index within the key, leaving any character not in the alphabet in place.

Comment: This looks like some kind of classical cipher,  possibility a rotation cipher,  used in some "hacking challenge" that really has nothing to do with security or modern cryptography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step to break the cipher would be do a frequency attack on it. Should be particularly effective in case of a Caesar cipher.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis

There are also a whole bunch of tools to help you, all posted under scientific curiosity :)

http://csc.fsksm.utm.my/syed/projects/cryptography.html

Comment: thans for you replay. yeah i already did frequency analysis and as i have written i already know the decryption for each letter. (look at the image link i posted), but i cannot find out wich type of a caesar cipher this should be.

Comment: did you try to do it on words, i.e. see which word is most frequent and try to figure out what it is?